# I want to develop a Spider web graph/Radar graph using Highchart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I would like to develop a Spider Web Radar which looks similar to the graph shown in image below using highcharts. can you please tell me wether this could be achieved using High charts. please check the below code and image attached

This is my approach [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rohithkumar_rk/3ky7og24/115/).

[image]

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    polar: true,
    type: 'area',
},
legend: {
  enabled: false
},

title: {
    text: 'Budget vs spending',
    x: -90
},

pane: {
    size: '90%'
},

xAxis: {
   categories: ['Bonds', 'Future', 'Past', 'Value', 'Health', 'Divedend'],
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    lineWidth: 0
},

yAxis: {
    gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
    lineWidth: 0,
    min: 0,
    labels:
                    {
                enabled: false
                    }
},

tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
},
series: [{
color: {
            linearGradient: {
                x1: 0,
                y1: 0,
                x2: 1,
                y2: 0
            },
            stops: [
                [0, '#50e3c2'],
                [1, '#50e3c2']
            ]
        },
        marker: {
            enabled: false,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    radius: 8,
                    symbol: 'square',
                }
            }
        },
    name: 'Allocated Budget',
    data: [80, 70, 60, 70, 70, 60],
    pointPlacement: 'on',
    shadow: {
        color: '#000000',
        width: 7,
        opacity: 0.08,
        offsetY: 3,
        offsetX: 0
        },
}]
});
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current solution? Aside from a gradient and some borders, it looks pretty identical

Comment: The client is not satisfied with my solution. They want the graph to look exactly the same way in looks in that image.

Comment: Hi @Rohithkumar - then you need to disable lines on your chart (xAxis line and series line). Then add [gradient](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors) to your chart. I would also consider using [styled-mode](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/gradients-shadows-and-patterns) as your chart looks like more CSS customization than programming.